# ¿Qué significa "El Pueblo Presidente"?

Tags: definiciones, nicaragua

El lema principal del gobierno actual de Nicaragua es: [*El Pueblo Presidente!*](http://www.elpueblopresidente.com/). ¿Qué significa eso exactamente? ¿Hay un "es" tácito (diciendo que el pueblo *es* presidente)? ¿O se usa *presidente* como adjetivo (diciendo lo mismo)? ¿O falta una coma, y le está exclamando "El Pueblo" *al* presidente? ¿O algo más?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esa construcción es común para expresar consignas de reivindicación, victoria, etc... y son habituales en manifestaciones, elecciones, deportes...

> ¡Zapatero presidente!
>
> ¡Rajoy dimisión!
>
> ¡Olano ganador!
>
> ¡Cuba libre!
>
> ¡El pueblo presidente!

Efectivamente, el verbo se omite. En el caso que comentas, podría ser:

> El pueblo (es) presidente
>
> El pueblo (debe ser) presidente
>
> (Queremos que) el pueblo (sea) presidente

O un significado similar.

Answer (score 9):

Me parece que te estás complicando demasiado, puesto que la palabra "presidente" sólo puede acompañar al sujeto como adjetivo.

Así pues, esta frase significa que es "el pueblo" el que preside, es decir, el que gobierna y es depositario del poder.

Comment: No se está complicando, tiene toda la razón. En esos casos (reivindicaciones, consignas, gritos, etc...) no se usa presidente como adjetivo sino como sustantivo, con un verbo omitido.

Comment: Aquí no hay verbo omitido de ninguna clase. Presidente actúa siempre como epíteto, al igual que en la mayor parte de ejemplos que citas a continuación (a excepción de del de "dimisión"). Tanto tu respuesta como la pregunta introducen complicaciones y redundancias innecesarias, ya que evidentemente cualquier adjetivación es susceptible de ser interpretada (y de hecho debe ser así) como el otorgamiento de  ciertas propiedades sobre el elemento calificado. Cosa distinta es calificar el acompañamiento de exclamaciones, en cuyo caso se entenderá que se trata de un contexto de reivindicación.

Comment: Acabo de consultar a una filóloga hispánica y me ha confirmado que esas frases son con verbo omitido. En concreto me ha dicho: ¡Zapatero presidente! = Zapatero queremos que seas presidente. ¡Zapatero dimisión! = Zapatero queremos tu dimisión. ¿Epíteto? Por favor, no confundas al personal http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ep%C3%ADteto que bastante tienen ya con aprender lo básico como para enseñarles mal lo complicado...

Comment: No quiero comenzar un debate estéril, pero creo que tanto tú como tu amiga estáis bastante confundidos (además de que cuestiones lingüísticas como esta se prestan a discusión). 

Dos cosas:

- Es conveniente separar sintáxis de intencionalidad. En este caso (aplicando el ejemplo SÓLO para adjetivos), mi explicación es rigurosamente cierta, puesto que este tipo de acompañamientos suponen condición necesaria pero no suficiente para sostener tu argumentación, cosa que no ocurre con sustantivos.

- Yo he calificado de epíteto al adjetivo "presidente", lo cual es estrictamente cierto en democracia.

Comment: El pueblo presidente, lo que los sandinistas quieren decir con esta frase es que es el pueblo quien es presidente... El Pueblo Presidente! intenta recalcar que es la gente común quien tiene el poder en Nicaragua.

Comment: Mi intención es responder a la pregunta de la manera más clara y directa posible, que es "¿Qué significa "El pueblo presidente!"?" y la duda de si hay algún verbo/intencionalidad implícitos en esa frase. En mi respuesta está mi punto de vista y algunos ejemplos. En el colegio se estudia que un epíteto es "un adjetivo que no añade ninguna información suplementaria a la del sustantivo con el cual concuerda" y suele usarse como recurso estilístico. El típico ejemplo estudiando en el colegio: la fría nieve. Creo que aquí no viene a cuento ni aporta nada a quien ha hecho la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Caben más interpretaciones? Por supuesto, pero creo que para alguien que apenas sabe castellano y hace esa pregunta enzarzarse en un debate erudito sobre tecnicismos es absurdo. No hablemos ya sobre recursos estilísticos como el epíteto que, repito, además aquí no tienen sentido. Tienes más ejemplos aquí: http://www.retoricas.com/2009/06/5-ejemplos-de-epiteto.html

Comment: Pues tienes razón. Quizá he pecado de ortodoxo. Un saludo.